# Crating a type of array of multiple objects

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to create a type for an array of objects. The array of objects can look like this:

```
   const troll = [
      {
        a: 'something',
        b: 'something else'
      },
      {
        a: 'something',
        b: 'something else'
      }
    ];
```

the type i am trying to use is:

```
export type trollType = [{ [key: string]: string }];
```

Then i want to use the type like this:

```
   const troll: trollType = [
      {
        a: 'something',
        b: 'something else'
      },
      {
        a: 'something',
        b: 'something else'
      }
    ];
```

but i get this error:

```
Type '[{ a: string; b: string; }, { a: string; b: string; }]' is not assignable to type 'trollType'.
  Source has 2 element(s) but target allows only 1
```

I can do something like this:

```
export type trollType = [{ [key: string]: string }, { [key: string]: string }];
```

but lets say my array of object will have 100 objects in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting a type for an array it should in this format `any[]`.

So in your case

```
export type trollType = { [key: string]: string }[];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the `Record` type for storing the object attribute definitions and create an array out of it, like in the following:

```
type TrollType = Record<string, string>[];

const troll: TrollType = [
      {
        a: 'something',
        b: 'something else'
      },
      {
        a: 'something',
        b: 'something else'
      }
    ];
```